# In case of Pagination, how can I increase spacing between the page number buttons?

Tags: java, javafx, pagination, styling

Presently, the page number buttons are being displayed as follows:

[image: Page Number Buttons]

I tried using:

1. `pagination.setStyle("-fx-padding: 10 10 10 10;");`
2. `pagination.setStyle("-fx-spacing: 10;");`
3. `pagination.setStyle("-fx-background-insets: 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0");`

But neither worked.

I searched for the same question on the site but didn't find any solution. Please suggest a solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: In general, you can use [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) or the [CSS analyzer in SceneBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/scene-builder-2/user-guide/stylesheet-support.htm#JSBRG150) to diagnose CSS styling.  You can also review the default [modena.css stylesheet](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u40/rt/file/tip/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css) and the [JavaFX 8 CSS reference manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add spacing to the `HBox` in the Pagination control. The class name for the HBox is `control-box`. Add `-fx-spacing` to it.

```
.pagination .control-box {
    -fx-spacing: 10;
}
```